# Dynamic new field value based on multiple condition of other field value in Mongodb Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, dynamic, aggregation-framework, project, aggregation

I have some documents listed in a stage of aggregation pipeline like this:

```
[{
   obj1:{code:"123"},
   obj2:{code:"654"},
   obj3:{code:"abc"},
   obj4:{code:"xyz"},
   type:"obj1",
},{
   obj1:{code:"123"},
   obj2:{code:"654"},
   obj3:{code:"abc"},
   obj4:{code:"xyz"},
   type:"obj2",
},{
   obj1:{code:"123"},
   obj2:{code:"654"},
   obj3:{code:"abc"},
   obj4:{code:"xyz"},
   type:"obj4",
}]
```

In the same aggregation pipeline, Without using $switch cases, is it possible that in each objects we project the code field for it's respective type value in $project stage?

Result should be:

```
[{
    obj1:{code:"123"},
    obj2:{code:"654"},
    obj3:{code:"abc"},
    obj4:{code:"xyz"},
    type:"obj1",
    code:$type.code // should return "123"
},{
    obj1:{code:"123"},
    obj2:{code:"654"},
    obj3:{code:"abc"},
    obj4:{code:"xyz"},
    type:"obj2",
    code:$type.code // should return "654"
},{
    obj1:{code:"123"},
    obj2:{code:"654"},
    obj3:{code:"abc"},
    obj4:{code:"xyz"},
    type:"obj4",
    code:$type.code // should return "xyz"
}]
```

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$objectToArray](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) first to be able to filter by your `$$ROOT` keys and then use [$filter](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to match against `type` field. The [$let](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) operator allows you to have it as one-stage pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $addFields: {
        code: {
            $let: {
                vars: { 
                    match: { 
                        $first: { 
                            $filter: { 
                                input: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" }, 
                                cond: { $eq: [ "$type", "$$this.k" ] } 
                            } 
                        } 
                    } 
                },
                in: "$$match.v.code"
            }
        }
    }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wr4K_Y4Ofov)